# Backbone Collection.each method affects every second model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I trigger 'removeAll' on collection on click from outside. It looks like that:

Bind inside collection constructor:

```
$('.empty').click => this.removeAll()
```

Empty the cart:

```
removeAll: ->
this.each( (item) ->
  item.setQuantity(0)
)
```

But in only affects every other model.

Changing quantity to 0 triggers removal from collection. Which triggers cart's View re-render with removal of unused (quantity == 0) Model's Views.

That happens also when I simply log from inside the callback - I get only half of the messages...
EDIT: I get all the messages when I use console.log exclusively. So, does removing models from collection interferes with removing models from collection?

What's wrong?
RtL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably removing things from the collection at the same time you're iterating over it. For example, this simplified example:

```
class M extends Backbone.Model

class C extends Backbone.Collection
    model: M

c = new C([
    { id: 1, amount: 1 },
    { id: 2, amount: 1 },
    { id: 3, amount: 6 }
])

c.on('change:amount', (m) ->
     c.remove(m) if(m.get('amount') == 0)
)

c.each (item) -> item.set(amount: 0)
```

will leave `c` with one model even though the `c.each` should have killed them all.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/4nKHE/

What's going on? Well, `c.each` will keep track of which element it is one as it iterates but `c.remove` will change the underlying array and `c.each` won't know that it has to adjust its "current element" index so things get lost. This is the class "altering a collection while iterating over it" problem with a bit of window dressing.

You can avoid the whole feedback problem by simply using [`reset`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-reset) to empty the collection:

```
$('.empty').click => this.reset()
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/tpLXW/

Once you have that sorted out, please stop binding to user interface elements inside your collections. You really should have `.empty` inside a view and then that view would have:

```
events:
    'click .empty': 'emptyCart'
emptyCart: ->
    @collection.reset()
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/gq3gv/